# What's the optimal strategy of this dice game?

Tags: probability, dice, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a dynamic programming problem. I want to find the optimal strategy and simulate it.

The game's description:

The player rolls two dice.

- If the numbers shown by the two dice are different then the player will add the sum given ($2+3$ for example) to the cumulative rewards he has.
- If the numbers shown by the two dice are equal then the player will loose all his reward.

I started modeling the problem. The state of the system is as follow: 
I chose one random number (300 for example) that may be the maximum reward for $N$ rounds game. The state is $V_k(S,D)$ where $S$ is the cumulative sum and $D$ is the sum of the two numbers shown on the two dice.

If we suppose that the numbers of rounds is finite, what will be the optimal strategy in a simple form?

In the case of infinite game what's the mean of the reward?

Reference : 
http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math56aS08/Math56a_S08_notes041.pdf

Thank you in advance guys :)

Comment: Oh, wait, maybe I mosread: In case of equal dice, will the player loose the *sum* from his reward or will he loose *all* his reward?

Comment: he will all his reward

Comment: Your description of the game is very lacking. As described there are no choices a player can make: an entire game consists of one person rolling two dice a single time. I can imagine a variety of *different* games that it sounds like you were trying to describe. Also, you don't state what you are trying to find a strategy *for*. (common options are "maximal expected score", "best odds of beating some target score", and "best odds of beating an opponent", although the game as described is a single-player game....)

Comment: Hi Hurkyl,
This is a dynamic programming problem. I'm looking for an optimal strategy to maximize the expected score. It is not a game theory problem. It is a single-player game. In another way, when should the player stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When to stop depends on how many rounds you're allowed to play. If you're allowed to play for arbitrary many rounds, you could decide not to stop until you have a million points. Then with probability $1$ sooner or later (most likely *much* later) you will leave the table with a million points.

So the game is only interesting when there's a time limit after which you *must* stop playing and leave with whatever you've got at that time if you haven't cashed out before that.

A *strategy* is a function $f(N,S)$ that gives our decision to either cash out or keep playing as the output of two inputs: $N$ is the number of rounds left, and $S$ is how many points you have when you make the decision. The fact that you're supposed to use dynamic programming is a hint that you're *not* supposed to find an explicit formula for $f(N,S)$, but rather to compute a *table* of values for $f(N,S)$.

It is easy enough to analyze what the optimal choice for $N=1$ is. If you quit now your expected winnings are $S$; if you play the last round your expected winnings are $\frac16 0 + \frac56(S+7)$, (since a roll that doesn't bankrupt you wins you 7 points on average). So you should play the last round iff $\frac {5S}6 + \frac{35}6 \ge S$ which is if $S\le 35$.

In order for you to proceed to $N=2$ you need to compute an auxiliary table of the *expected* value of the game *before* you make the $f(1,S)$ for various $S$. For large enough $S$ you should always cash out, in which case the expected value is $S$ itself -- so you only need to tabulate the expected values for $S$ less than the cash-out threshold.

Now you can compute $f(2,S)$ as follows: The expected value of walking out is $S$. To find the expected value of playing, consider the various outcomes of the dice roll: you could go bankrupt or win 3, 4, 5, ..., 10, 11 points, each with a particular probablity. Each of these cases take you to a state $(1,S')$ that you have already computed the expected value of; the appropriately weighted average of those expectations is the value of going on. Compare this with $S$ to figure out if you should leave or go on.

Now do the same thing for $f(3,-)$, $f(4,-)$ and so forth, until you reach the actual length of your game.

(Note that the actual strategic *decisions* can be made in constant time on the fly if only you have tabulated the *values* of the game at each possible state).

Comment: Should $\frac S6 + \frac{35}6$ be $\frac {5S}6 + \frac{35}6$?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Hm, yes it should. And that changes the threshold to $S\le 35$. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, the optimal strategy for this game is to play until you run out of rolls or $S\geq 35$, whichever comes first.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Really? So if I have 36 points and a quadrillion turns left, I should stop? That sounds counterintuitive; if I roll and lose, I'll have plenty of time to attempt to reach 36 once more afterwards -- so continuing is _almost_ a no-loss proposition for me there.

Comment: Sorry I assume that at the first loss, you go to zero and the game ends. I'm not sure if the OP meant this or not.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Okay, that's a different assumption than mine.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that when you lose all your money the game is over and you are not allowed to play anymore. Under this assumption, you should **not** keep rolling even with unlimited rolls available, because if you play too long, you'll eventually hit zero and lose everything.

Starting with $S$ dollars, the expected amount after rolling the dice one more time is
$$0\,{6\over 36}+(S+3){2\over 36}+(S+4){2\over 36}+(S+5){3\over 36}+\cdots+(S+11){2\over 36}= {5\over 6}S+{35\over 6}.$$
The first term, with value zero, corresponds to rolling doubles and losing all your money. 
Otherwise, your money increases by anything from 3 to 11 dollars.

The optimal strategy is to play until either you run out of rolls, or the current amount $S$ is greater than or equal to ${5\over 6}S+{35\over 6}$, i.e. $S\geq 35.$ 
In the latter case, the risk in losing your fortune outweighs the potential gains, so it is better to stop.

For $S\geq 1$, the value function for the game with $N\geq 0$ rolls is 
$$v^N(S)=\cases{35-(5/6)^N(35-S)&for $S\leq 35$\cr S&for $S\geq 35$.}$$
This is the expected payoff when you start with $S$ dollars and follow the optimal strategy.